# How to solve the error In CachedNetworkImage?

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to load an image to cache. So I used CachedNetworkImage for that. When a user logged in through gmail account I get the image url and show the image. But I need to keep it in cache.
Here is my code:

```
new Center(
 child: new Column(
  children: <Widget>[
   new CircleAvatar(
    new CachedNetworkImage(
      placeholder: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      imageUrl: widget.currentUser?.profilUrl,
    ),
  ),
],
),
)
```

I used CachedNetworkImageProvider also but same error is coming for both. The error is

```
type'CachedNetworkImage'is not  a  subtype  of  type  'ImageProvider<dynamic>'
```

Comment: you can try out Circular Profile Avatar package available for flutter. I hope it will help you to do same job.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The widget [CircleAvatar](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/CircleAvatar-class.html) receives an [ImageProvider](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/painting/ImageProvider-class.html).

The [cached_network_image](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/cached_network_image) package offers you two classes to use:

1. `CachedNetworkImage` a **Widget** you can use to display a cached network image.
2. `CachedNetworkImageProvider` an **ImageProvider** providing the cached image.

Therefore you gotta use `CachedNetworkImageProvider`(2.), if you want to pass it to the `CircleAvatar`.

Here is a **complete** example, that you can copy & paste for trying out:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: CircleAvatar(
            backgroundImage: CachedNetworkImageProvider(
              'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/71/Bill_Gates_Buys_Skype_%285707954468%29.jpg/2560px-Bill_Gates_Buys_Skype_%285707954468%29.jpg'
            ),
          ),
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I used `CachedNetworkImageProvider` but same kind of error is showing.

Comment: @Falak I added a complete example, you can copy & paste it and try it out. Is the same kind of error still showing up?

Answer (score 3):

CircleAvatar `backgroundImage` property need ImageProvider , Not a Image widget.

**ImageProviders** :- NetworkImage(), AssetImage() & CachedNetworkImageProvider().

**Image Widgets** :- Image() , CircleAvatar() , CachedNetworkImage()

So CircleAvatar() & CachedNetworkImage() is also a image displaying widget same as Image() widget, that we used in generally.

Every image displaying widgets need image providers.
**So in this case you have to use CircleAvatar() widget with CachedNetworkImageProvider()**, because this CachedNetworkImageProvider() provide image data that needs by CircleAvatar() widget.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether it may help someone but he mention how to handle network image error. I usually used **Image.Network(Flutter build widget)** to handle such errors. this is an example

```
Image.network(
   products[index].image!,
  errorBuilder: (BuildContext context,Object exception,StackTrace 
  stackTrace) {
    return Image.asset('img/no_image.png');
     },)
```

the **errorbuilder** help to show another image in case network image has not been successfully found.

Answer (score 0):

Just like @Niklas say.

> The widget CircleAvatar receives an ImageProvider.

this is how to use:

```
 new Center(
  child: new Column(
   children: <Widget>[
    new CircleAvatar(
     backgroundImage: new CachedNetworkImageProvider(
      widget.currentUser?.profilUrl,
     )
    ),
   ],
  ),
 )
```